# More TAG attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I've been having a problem with assigning Color to GradientStop in a trigger (because trigger cannot target a GradientStop element). So I read some article about this and found solution with using Tag. Here is my code:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1.5" x:Name="border">
    <Border.Tag>
        <Color>#FF28AAE6</Color>
    </Border.Tag>

    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=Tag}" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0A78AA" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>

<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Tag" Value="#FF46C8FF" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But I need to set more values in that trigger - Color for the second GradientStop. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you really need to change every GradientStop separately?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the Background to the a new brush that you want it to be instead of trying to update the brush properties?

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF46C8FF" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0A78AA" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

If you do need to do it your way, you could create some Canvases with `Visibilty="Collapsed"` and use `ElementBinding` to get the colours from those

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1.5" x:Name="border">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="{Binding ElementName=Canvas1, Path=Tag}" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="{Binding ElementName=Canvas2, Path=Tag}" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid>
            <Canvas Name="Canvas1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Canvas.Tag>
                    <Color>#FF28AAE6</Color>
                </Canvas.Tag>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas Name="Canvas2" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Canvas.Tag>
                    <Color>#FF0A78AA</Color>
                </Canvas.Tag>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Canvas1" Property="Tag" Value="Yellow" />
            <Setter TargetName="Canvas2" Property="Tag" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to update the brush properties because (when there is only one property) it needs much less code. But that canvas thing is even longer...